# DataBase in Heroku Discord.py

Tags: python, database, heroku, discord.py

My discord.py bot can play music, and add songs to the queue. It uses a database to work on multiple servers at once. When queued it writes the database file and adds a song to one of the tables or something like that. When I use it on my local PC, it works fine but when I try to use it on Heroku, it doesn't play anything. It doesn't give ANY errors at all. It says `playing queued song` but It doesn't play it. This is the log:

[image]

As you guys can see after saying `playing next song` it just finishes it. I think add-ons would help but idk what to use!

I can give the code If you guys need it.

EDIT: The Code https://pastebin.com/JRUTdwjR

Comment: Please provide the code.

Comment: Is there a git repo? `Procfile`, name of the file, `requirements.txt` are relevant.

Comment: Yes, there is. The bot runs perfectly outside the next system

Comment: Provide the content of `requirements.txt`. 
Remove the try except block that prints `No more queued song(s)`. You are suppressing valuable error traceback message there and post the new errors.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SHfLXN5D1G9-zEh8yW9IS8UagVFSMe2L/view?usp=sharing